# How to prevent py.tests from running if an essential requisite is not met?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am looking for a way to prevent tests from being executed when, for example, a required test server cannot be contacted.

Is essential to be able to detect this before starting to execute the tests, and failing as fast as possible.

The tests are run using py.test or using tox which calls py.test.

I do have a piece of code that detects if the tests server is up, but I don't know which is the right place to put this into.

Initially I assumed that this would be a global fixture but that's not quite true as it would mean that will run for each test and what I want is not to run them, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `skipif` for skipping tests.

I have a function, which returns True or False based on the availability of the program I need:

```
  def have_gpg():
    try:
        subprocess.call(['gpg', '--version'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
    return True
```

Then for tests I need to skip if GPG is not present, I use skipif:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif("not have_gpg()")
def test_gpg_decode(tmpdir):
    ...
    assert out = 'test'
```

See more [documentation on skipif](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html).